# What is the grammatical function of 'that' in Shelley's poem?

Tags: that-it

I am trying to determine the grammatical function of *that* in the line:

- *The hand **that** mock'd them and the heart **that** fed.*

from Shelley's *Ozymandius*.
I want to work out if 'that' is being used as a pronoun or an adverb.

Comment: How far have you gotten in working that out?

Comment: The [meaning of the lines themselves](http://www.shmoop.com/ozymandias/section-1-lines-1-8-summary.html) is still open to debate, even after two centuries; some poems are like that. The function of _that_, however, is quite clear: in both clauses, it is a relative pronoun, the subject of _mock'd_ and of _fed_, introducing [relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html) modifying _hand_ and _heart_, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler notes in the comments:

> The function of *that*, however, is quite clear: in both clauses, it is a relative pronoun, the subject of *mock'd* and of *fed*, introducing [relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html) modifying *hand* and *heart*, respectively.

Answer (score -5):

It's actually neither. It's an adjective, modifying the nouns of the sentence for greater specificity. Which hand? That hand. Which heart? That heart.

If it were a pronoun, it would be "the heart, that is what fed them". If it were an adverb, it'd be "the hand mock'd them that much."

Comment: You really need to adjust your understanding with regard to the parts of speech. You could start with the Wikipedia article on pronouns, where 'that' is said to be used as a relative pronoun (the hand that mocked them) as well as a demonstrative pronoun (That is mine) sometimes used anaphorically (The heart: that is what fed them). Next, check on determiners (as opposed to adjectives). You really don't want me to go into 'adverbs'.

Comment: Okay, but was it really necessary to be rude?

Comment: Firm. And when someone puts up so magisterial an answer which could mislead people so badly, I'd feel I was erring if I didn't counter it so firmly.